# Unsubscribe message retrieved by NavigationView

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am working on Xamarin Android Application.I am stuck at how to unsubscribe message retrieved by NavigationView.
I have tried :

```
public override void OnDestroyView ()
{
    messenger.Unsubscribe<UserLoginMessage> (_token);
    base.OnDestroyView ();
}
```

This is how I subscribe Message in navigationview :

```
 public class MenuFragment : MvxFragment<MenuViewModel>, NavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    public TextView LoginUserName;
    public ImageView ProfilePicture;
    public IMvxMessenger messenger;
    public MvxSubscriptionToken _token;
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignore = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_navigation, null);

        navigationView = view.FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.Menu.FindItem (Resource.Id.nav_home).SetChecked (true);
        navigationView.Menu.FindItem (Resource.Id.nav_LogOut).SetVisible (false);           

         messenger = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
        _token = messenger.SubscribeOnMainThread<UserLoginMessage>(Login_Info,MvxReference.Strong);

        return view;
    }
```

But it is not unsubscribing message and I am getting message twice.
What is the solution ?Please Help!

Comment: Are you using the MessagingCenter to do the subscriptions? If so, what does your subscription code look like?

Comment: I am using IMvxMessenger

Comment: have you tried `_token.Dispose()` ? If not, then maybe show some more of your code... are you sure you are only subscribing once?

Comment: I have tried _token.Dispose().But it's not working.@Stuart